# Need to use existing list to create doc library based on template

Tags: 2007, list, library, import, template

I have an existing list with many items. I have created a doc library with the same columns as the list and associated a template with the library. I created a workflow to pull items from the list and create a new document in the library - HOWEVER, when opening the document, it appears blank, not in the template. If I click "new" in the doc library, the correct template opens and I can create a new document properly. I do not want to do this for the 500 list items.

tl;dr How can I import a list to a doc library so that the documents can be printed using a template?

edited to add: I'm using SharePoint 2007 and Word 2010.

---

This was ugly, but this is what I ended up doing:

1. Download List to Excel file, save to local drive
2. open previously-created template in Word
3. run mail merge wizard, using the Excel file as source
4. Do not insert any mail merge fields
5. Use split merge tool (found at http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm)
   and use ID (from excel list) as doc name
6. save docs to local drive (you can also save to sharepoint folder location, but I had a huge number of documents and it would have been too slow)
7. Copy to SharePoint doc lib folder (Actions > Open With Windows Explorer)
8. after docs saved, go to doc lib, create a datasheet view with the same column order as the list and sort by Name (i.e., ID)
9. create a calculated field in the list with the formula `=Text(ID,"0")` and create a view that sorts by this field

   - This is because the Name field is text, and thus the list field you sort by must also be text, otherwise the list will be 1, 2, 3, 4 and the library will be 1, 10, 2, 20, etc.
10. Copy/paste from list datasheet view into doc lib datasheet view
11. metadata cannot be edited within the document itself (doc properties okay), better to edit in the SharePoint view.